# What am I doing wrong on this php PDO

Tags: php, pdo

So when I run this below it outputs an error Catchable fatal error: Object of class eg could not be converted to string

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
    require_once '../dbfolder/'.$class.'.php';  
});

$mysql = dbWrapper::getDbInstance();

class eg 
{
    private $username = 'paul';
    private $email = 'paul@yahoo.com';

    public function eg_()
    {
        global $mysql;  

        $sql = "INSERT INTO users(username,email)VALUES(:username,:email)";
        $prepared = $mysql->$this->handler->prepare($sql);

        $prepared->bindParam(':username',$this->username);
        $prepared->bindParam(':email',$this->email);
        $prepared->execute();
    }
}

$eg = new eg();
$eg->eg_();
```

Please can anyone just point out for me what am doing wrong?

Comment: @AlbertoFernández sorry i dont get what you mean but it works fine for me like that if the pdo is working fine.

Comment: Hay rapulu. Its kind of bad form to _eat and run_ If the answer fixed your problem, then accept the answer. It lets others know the question has been answered and thanks the answerer with a few points on their reputation.

Answer (score 0):

This line is the problem:

```
$prepared = $mysql->$this->handler->prepare($sql);
```

PHP thinks you're trying to use it's [variable variable](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) feature. It sees `$mysql->$this` and tries to convert `$this` into a string, which the current class does not support (no `__toString()` magic method). I assume this is a typo/copy-paste error.

To fix it, all you need is to remove it (assuming your `$mysql` object has a property of `handler` that is):

```
$prepared = $mysql->handler->prepare($sql);
```

Comment: If this solved your issue, please click the checkmark on the left of the answer.